# Blazor WASM PUT request being converted to POST

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my Blazor WASM project I have the following code:-

```cs
var response = await _client.PutAsJsonAsync($"/subscriptions/{paymentId}", new
            {
                subscriptionId,
                quantity,
                successUrl,
                cancelUrl
            });
```

However, it is making a `POST` request instead of a `PUT`. So I am getting a `405` back from the API server.

Comment: It's weird!, it should make a PUT request. Could you share server side code? OR if you can create a sample code repo. to reproduce this issue there.